# Number of watchers adding up with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The below code renders tabs, sections under each tab and the content of the section. When navigating from one section to another, I notice the number of watchers are increasing (or) adding up each time.

Can any one tell what could be the reason for this. Appreciate any pointers

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li ng-repeat="tab in tabList track by tab.tabId" id="{{tab.attribute}}"
                    ng-class="{active:selectedTab.attribute === '{{tab.attribute}}'}">
                    <a showtab="" href="#{{tab.attribute}}" ng-click="setSelectedTab(tab)">{{tab.displayLabel}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-pane">
                <div class="" ng-if="selectedTab.sectionList.length > 0">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills pills-section">
                        <li ng-repeat="section in selectedTab.sectionList track by section.sectionId" id="{{section.attribute}}" ng-class="{active:selectedSection.attribute === '{{section.attribute}}'}">
                            <a showtab="" href="#{{section.attribute}}" ng-click="setSelectedSection(section)">{{section.displayLabel}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Content of the section rendered with ng-repeat -->
                    <div ng-include="sectionContent"/>
               </div>
            </div>
```

The section content has the below mark up

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="field in selectedSection.fields track by field.fieldId">
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: The page performance deteriorates when switching from one section to another, I noticed through Batrang, the number of watchers are doubling each time and the digest cycle takes more time. I believe its because of the the nested ng-repeats,  the watchers on the section content are adding up event though the lists are cleared each time switching between the sections.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems before, nesting ng-repeats is never a good idea, but we are forced from time to time to do it. This is your solution to have performance benefits.

http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/